# SQL Server installation

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

I have installed Visual Studio 2008 on my system (Windows Vista). I'm trying to install SQL Server 2005 to run applications. While installing I got only the configuration tools and no SQL Server Management Studio IDE. Where do I get that?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to select "Workstation Components" while installing SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you check Client Component when Feature selection[select the program features you want installed.]?

Comment: ya..thats my mistake...i reinstalled by insluding client components too...thankc